# How to apply a secondary sort for ruby array with reversed sort direction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have a ruby array in the format of `[["Anna",70],["Billy",90],["Billy",100]]`...

I know I can apply secondary sort using the following

```
sort_by{ |o| [o.name, o.score]}
```

However I want to sort first on Name asc and then sort on Score but descending. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily do it with

```
sort_by{ |o| [o.name, -o.score]}
```